# How do you merge and switch keys with values if they have same values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary with these keys and values :

```
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 5,'foo1' : 1,'bar1' : 1,'foo2': 5}
```

I can't zip them like this

```
dict(zip(my.values(),my.keys()))
```

because this happens :

```
{1: 'foo', 5: 'bar'}
```

What I would like to be my output is :

```
{1:{'bar1','foo','foo1'},5:{'bar','foo2'}}
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid python. Do you want a list of values per key?

Comment: The output you presented is not a dictionary nor a list

Comment: Your output is not a valid structure in Python. I believe what you want to do is: `{1: ['bar1','foo','foo1'] ,5:['bar','foo2']}`

Comment: No, it's not duplicate, it's different from what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple values for a given key, so the values in such a data structure need to be lists. You can't do this transformation easily with `zip()`; you'll need a `for` loop:

```
my = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 5, 'foo1': 1, 'bar1': 1,'foo2': 5}
rev = {}

for k, v in my.items():
    rev.setdefault(v, []).append(k)
```

From the edits in your question, it appears that you want to use a set for the values. This is also straightforward:

```
for k, v in my.items():
    rev.setdefault(v, set()).add(k)
```

You can also use a `defaultdict` as Daniel has suggested, but it seems overkill here to do an import just for that. Depending on the size of your dictionary it might be a little faster, since using `setdefault()` we are continuously creating and throwing away empty containers.

Comment: That's sums up what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in my.items():
    result[v].append(k)
```

Comment: That's pretty much what I want but I want it as set, I editted my post, check that.

Comment: @BlueMonday And you can't at least guess what you would have to change in Daniel's code to use a set instead?

Comment: @Vincent Savard not really, I tried changing 'defaultdict(set)' but in that case I can't append to set..

Comment: And how can you add a value to a set? Have you looked into the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

For a one-liner with a functional twist (probably neither the most readable nor performant code, though):

```py
import itertools, operator

my_dict = {'foo': 1, 'bar': 5, 'foo1' : 1,'bar1' : 1, 'foo2': 5}

inverse_dict = { k:map(operator.itemgetter(0), v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)), operator.itemgetter(1)) }
```

To aggregate using a set, just wrap the mapped value in a set constructor.

```
inverse_dict = { k:set(map(operator.itemgetter(0), v)) for k, v in itertools.groupby(sorted(my_dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)), operator.itemgetter(1)) }
```